# Include asyncsocket in iPad project

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, asyncsocket

I am having a heck of time loading asyncsocket into my iPad project so I can start using it. So far I added the AsyncSocket.h and .m classes and loaded CFNetwork.framework and made sure all the paths line up - but I'm getting 6522 errors as I try to build.

The first error is Block.h: no such file or directory.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: What file is trying to load Block.h?

Comment: Could you give more details ? I added these classes last week, either TCP and UDP without any problems.

Comment: Yah, sorry this is really unclear, but I don't know how to describe so many errors... Did you add these classes on the iPad? I know they work on the iPhone with no issues. If you could just describe the steps you  took - I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumb mistake... realized that I was loading CFNetwork.framework version 4.1 which isn't available on iPad.. you have to load 3.2